# flutter TextField and CupertinoTextField what are the differences?

Tags: flutter

I just saw both `TextField` and `CupertinoTextField` but I couldn't tell the differences.
Anyone can explain what the differences between them?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation puts in quite clearly:

A [CupertinoTextField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTextField-class.html) is an iOS-style text field.

On the other hand a [TextField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) is a material design text field; its a material design counterpart for the `CupertinoTextField`. See also [Material Design](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field) UI conventions to understand what is Google's Material Design.

Visually they look somewhat different, but  in terms of functionality they resemble each other closely.